# Is it possible to query the JavaScriptCore event loop?

Tags: ios, cocoa, javascriptcore

If I'm running some JavaScript in my iOS app using JavaScriptCore, is it possible for my native code to query whether the JavaScript is currently processing an event, and/or whether there are events waiting to be immediately processed next?

Scenario: the running JS is managing some state, and I want my UI thread to occasionally query the JS for that state, but I don't want to risk waiting too long if the JS is busy processing other events first.

Answer (score 2):

I investigated a bit more, and discovered that there's a surprising answer for this question: there is no javascript event loop in JSCore, if you don't implement it.

To add further detail, execution of javascript code is always synchronous with the ObjC function that invokes it, and there is no method in Javascript to generate asynchronous execution: no `setTimeout`, no `setInterval`, no DOM and `addEventListener`. You have to implement these function natively, and then you have to decide the scheduling policy. If your JSContext is attached to a WebView or similar browser-like context, the WebView provides these events, and you may not be able to access them in the way you want. In this case however you may use something like [Zone.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js) to monkey patch all functions which may generate events and implement in Javascript something that tracks what you want (which is something that's done in the video of the presentation of the technology, in the linked page)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick perusal of the API source here:
https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS/tree/master/JavaScriptCore/API

I don't see any function on the `JSContext` or `JSVirtualMachine` that would get you the information you're interested in.

As an alternative, you could do a callback to your ObjC code from JS each time the JS code begin/ends processing an event, and then store state information in the ObjC side so you can quickly determine if you believe the JSVM is processing an event or not.

Comment: Thanks, and interesting idea. That'd require me to explicitly call the ObjC callback in every JS event handler, right? Is there any simple way to do that globally in one place?

Comment: I would assume you know what code is being run, so you could just hook the long running commands you are having the JS VM run?

Comment: Hooking into any function which can create async code execution is what Zone js (a part of Angular) does. The reason it does so in Angular is to detect changes to properties which may require UI redraw. Have a look at it, and see if it fits your purpose and can be used without the full Angular framework